# How to update WPF binding from a helper class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm sure this is a very basic question but I don't even know the technical term / jargon to Google and self-educate on.

I have created a simple model implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class PushNotes : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string CompletePushNotes { get; set; }

}
```

Binding in cs:

```
        evt_pushNotes = new PushNotes()
        {
            CompletePushNotes = "HelloThere"
        };

        this.DataContext = evt_pushNotes;

       //snip later in code

      Helpers.UpdateCompletePushNotes();
```

In XAML:

```
<xctk:RichTextBox x:Name="PushEmail" Text="{Binding Path=CompletePushNotes, Mode=OneWay}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="40,398,40,40">
        <xctk:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
            <xctk:PlainTextFormatter />
        </xctk:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
    </xctk:RichTextBox>
```

Helper:

```
internal static class Helpers
{
   internal static void UpdateCompletePushNotes()
   {
         //duhhhh what do I do now??
       //If I create a new PushNotes it will be a different instantiation....???
   }
}
```

Now this is all fine but I have a method in a helper class that needs to change the CompletePushNotes.

Again I know this is a simplistic / newbie question but I don't know what I need to learn.

So do I make my PushNotes class static, or singleton. Is there some global binding "tree" I can walk to find my instantiated and bound PushNotes class that is attached to the UI element?

Not looking for an a handout just need to know what it is I'm looking for.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PushNotes class does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Once you have implemented it, you need to modify your CompletePushNotes property to have a backing field and in the setter of the property you can raise the PropertyChanged event to notify the UI of the source property update.

```
public class PushNotes : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string completePushNotes;
    public string CompletePushNotes
    {
        get
        {
            return completePushNotes;
        }

        set
        {
            completePushNotes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Making the PushNotes class static will not help you. You seem to have a variable of some sort to the PushNotes instance (evt_pushNotes), so just do:

```
evt_pushNotes.CompletePushNotes = something;
```

If you have a helper class that does something, call the method in the helper class and get the value back or pass the PushNotes instance into the helper class as a parameter.

```
internal static class Helpers
{
   internal static void UpdateCompletePushNotes(PushNotes pushNotes)
   {
       pushNotes.CompletePushNotes = something;
   }
}
```

Comment: OK Cool...I've added that....how does my Helper class get at this specific instantiation?

Comment: I can't see how/where you are using the helper class.

Comment: Ahhh yes I was speaking theoretically as it wasn't my intent for people to spoon feed me. I'll update the OP>

Comment: @GPGVM: How do you plan on calling the Helper method?  Could you not pass in the instance you're planning on updating?

Comment: What is calling the UpdateCompletePushNotes method?

Comment: OK so you pass handle like anything else.